# WCF service, how to hide internal methods?

Tags: c#, accessor

In my WCF service, I have methods that are currently public, but I want to hide them from the outside world but be able to use them in my WCF service.

Is internal what I'm looking at?

Answer (score 2):

yes internal will limit access to the current assembly

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx

Comment: True it limits access, but it's not a complete answer. Really, "public" is ok as long as the developer doesn't openly expose them with the ServiceContract attribute as stated above.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do to not have the outside world ( WCF clients) know of them is to not mark them with [ServiceContract] attribute, then it doesn't matter if they are public

if you distribute the DLL with the WCF service in it you can mark the methods:

- private (can only be called from within the same class)
- protected (same as private + a class inheriting from it)
- internal (same as private + all other classes in the same assembly + any classes in assemblies which has been named in InternalsVisibleTo (google it)

Comment: thanks for the userfriendly definitions.  InternalsVisibleTo  is a new one!

Comment: I agree removing the [ServiceContract] decoration is the correct answer.